# Quickly Evaluating MANY matlabFunctions

Tags: matlab, gpu, symbols

This post builds on my post about quickly evaluating analytic Jacobian in Matlab:

[fast evaluation of analytical jacobian in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821785/fast-evaluation-of-analytical-jacobian-in-matlab)

The key difference is that now, I am working with the Hessian and I have to evaluate close to 700 matlabFunctions (instead of 1 matlabFunction, like I did for the Jacobian) each time the hessian is evaluated. So there is an opportunity to do things a little differently.

I have tried to do this two ways so far and I am thinking about implementing a third and was wondering if anyone has any other suggestions. I will go through each method with a toy example, but first some preprocessing to generate these matlabFunctions:

**PreProcessing:**

```
% This part of the code is calculated once, it is not the issue
dvs = 5;
X=sym('X',[dvs,1]);
num = dvs - 1; % number of constraints

% multiple functions
for k = 1:num
    f1(X(k+1),X(k)) = (X(k+1)^3 - X(k)^2*k^2);
    c(k) = f1;
end

gradc = jacobian(c,X).'; % .' performs transpose

parfor k = 1:num
    hessc{k} = jacobian(gradc(:,k),X);
end

parfor k = 1:num
    hess_name = strcat('hessian_',num2str(k));
    matlabFunction(hessc{k},'file',hess_name,'vars',X);
end
```

**METHOD #1 : Evaluate functions in series**

```
%% Now we use the functions to run an "optimization." Just for an example the "optimization" is just a for loop

fprintf('This is test A, where the functions are evaluated in series!\n');
tic
for q = 1:10

    x_dv = rand(dvs,1);   % these are the design variables
    lambda = rand(num,1); % these are the lagrange multipliers

    x_dv_cell = num2cell(x_dv); % for passing large design variables

    for k = 1:num
        hess_name = strcat('hessian_',num2str(k));
        function_handle = str2func(hess_name);
        H_temp(:,:,k) = lambda(k)*function_handle(x_dv_cell{:});
    end

    H = sum(H_temp,3);

end
fprintf('The time for test A was:\n')
toc
```

**METHOD # 2: Evaluate functions in parallel**

```
%% Try to run a parfor loop

fprintf('This is test B, where the functions are evaluated in parallel!\n');
tic
for q = 1:10

    x_dv = rand(dvs,1);   % these are the design variables
    lambda = rand(num,1); % these are the lagrange multipliers

    x_dv_cell = num2cell(x_dv); % for passing large design variables

    parfor k = 1:num
        hess_name = strcat('hessian_',num2str(k));
        function_handle = str2func(hess_name);
        H_temp(:,:,k) = lambda(k)*function_handle(x_dv_cell{:});
    end

    H = sum(H_temp,3);

end
fprintf('The time for test B was:\n')
toc
```

**RESULTS:**

METHOD #1 = 0.008691 seconds

METHOD #2 = 0.464786 seconds

**DISCUSSION of RESULTS**

This result makes sense because, the functions evaluate very quickly and running them in parallel waists a lot of time setting up and sending out the jobs to the different Matlabs ( and then getting the data back from them). I see the same result on my actual problem.

**METHOD # 3: Evaluating the functions using the GPU**

I have not tried this yet, but I am interested to see what the performance difference is. I am not yet familiar with doing this in Matlab and will add it once I am done.

Any other thoughts? Comments? Thanks!

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you `profile`ed your code? I'd suggest not bothering with the GPU for an application like this.

Comment: Yes, I profiled the code and the evaluation of these functions is the bottleneck.

Comment: tag 'hessian' if for network protocol hessian